# Issue with import after upgrading to webpack 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, umd

After upgrading to webpack 4 (from v3) and upgrading babel packages, import started to return this :

```
Module {__esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
auth: (...)
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
__esModule: true
get auth: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
```

I'm not sure why import changed...

Comment: Please read the doc about what a Good Stack Overflow question should contain [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
It would be useful to get more code. Maybe webpack configuration?

Comment: Can you add your webpack config and .babelrc if you have one?